# How to create a mobile friendly website [infrastructure]

Tags: css, mobile-website

if i wanted to create a mobile friendly version of a relatively small website would it be better to have a sub domain that redirects to a completely new url with separate markup and styling or would it be better to detect the user agent in code and programmatically change to a different mobile friendly stylesheet, or is their a better infrastructure based solution i am overlooking..

Thanks.

Comment: If you decide to redirect to some "mobile friendly" subdomain, please make sure that one can go back to the desktop version if they want to, and more importantly that *any* deeplink actually works in the redirect. I'm tired of clicking on links which then *force* mobile view just because I'm on an Android OS (although I have mobile view disabled), and lose any link information during that process, leaving me completely disoriented on some random website I did not have seen before... And all because someone on twitter wanted to share some link to an article... <_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SEO isn't really a concern, Using different stylesheets with the same HTML is much easier, in terms of maintenance.

Comment: could you plz explain more on how to do it?

Comment: You can use the media attribute of the link element to target specific devices. For example: <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" media="handheld"> will only target 'handheld' (mobile devices). You can use 'all' if you want a stylesheet to be applied to all device types. All the different media types are listed here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Answer (score 3):

You could try abit of both. Have the main site detect the useragent, then redirect to the completly new domain. That way its more automated but your main site code wont have tons of if statements depending on if its a mobile or not as the new domain would take care of that.

If you go with this tho, always add a link on the mobile site so that users can view the main site if they please... use cookies tho else youll end up getting redirected to the mobile site.